# Critical points of an autonomous dynamical systems depending on a parameter

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider the autonomous dynamical system:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\dot{x}=x+y-x^3-\alpha xy^2\\
\dot{y}=y-x-x^2y-y^3
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Prove that $(0,0)$ is the unique critical point if $\alpha\in(0,2)$.

**My work**: I tried to use polar coordinates but system with the change is not easier to work with. I also works algebraically with the system with variables $x,y$ and the parameter $\alpha$, but it didn't come to anything interesting either.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Assuming that the dynamic system is

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\dot x=x+y-x^3-\alpha xy^2\\
\dot y=y-x-x^2y-y^3
\end{array}
\right.
$$

we have

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
x\dot x=x^2+y x-x^4-\alpha x^2y^2\\
y\dot y=y^2-x y-x^2y^2-y^4
\end{array}
\right.
$$

and after addition

$$
\frac 12(x^2+y^2)'=x^2+y^2-(x^4+(1+\alpha)x^2y^2+y^4)
$$

now if $x^2+y^2-(x^4+(1+\alpha)x^2y^2+y^4) < 0$ the equilibrium point is $(0,0)$ **but** calculating the hessian at $(0,0)$ we found that

$$
H = \left(\matrix{2 & 0\\ 0 & 2}\right)
$$

which is positive definite hence no equilibrium point at $(0,0)$. At $(0,0)$ we have a source and for $a>0$ a limit cycle around $(0,0)$.

Attached a stream plot for $\alpha = 1$

[image]

NOTE

In polar coordinates, making $\{x = \rho \cos\theta, y = \rho\sin\theta\}$ we have

$$
\frac{1}{8} \rho ^2 \left((\alpha-1) \rho ^2 \cos (4 \theta )-(\alpha+7) \rho ^2+8\right) = 0
$$

and solving for $\rho$ we have

$$
\rho = \cases{0\\ \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\alpha+7-(\alpha-1) \cos (4 \theta )}}}
$$

and for $\alpha = 1$ we have $\rho = 1$ as depicted in the previous plot.

Comment: Those equations are not differential.

Comment: I cannot see how deduce that if $\alpha\in(0,2)$ then $(0,0)$ is the unique critical point.

Comment: Certainly for $\alpha \in (0,2)$ the origin is a source with a limit cycle around it. The origin is a source for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Okey, but the limit cycle is not a critical point. What I need to prove is that for $\alpha\in(0,2)$ the unique solution of $(\dot{x},\dot{y})=(0,0)$ is $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks @Cesareo, but I cannot see how to deduce from your NOTE that $\alpha\in(0,2)$ to be (0,0) the unique critical point.